# Live chat room event: Launch of JAXA Epsilon-1 with SPRINT-A on board (August 27, 2013 at 4:25 a.m. UTC/GMT)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, announcement, scheduled-event

**Update**: Today's launch was cancelled. More details will be reported as further information becomes available.

---

This is an invitation to attend [our chat room event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=schedule), where we will be covering the launch of the first [JAXA](http://www.jaxa.jp/) (Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency) [Epsilon Launch Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_%28rocket%29) (Epsilon-1) with the Spectroscopic Planet Observatory for Recognition of Interaction of Atmosphere (SPRINT-A) on board.

Chat event will start 20 minutes before the first launch window time.

[image]

Here's [JAXA press release](http://www.jaxa.jp/press/2013/08/20130825_epsilon_e.html):

> **Launch Time of the Epsilon-1 with SPRINT-A aboard**
>   
> August 25, 2013 (JST) Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency (JAXA)
>
> The Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency (JAXA) set the launch time of
>   the first Epsilon Launch Vehicle (Epsilon-1) with the Spectroscopic
>   Planet Observatory for Recognition of Interaction of Atmosphere
>   (SPRINT-A) onboard as follows:
>
> <s>Scheduled launch date: **August 27 (Tuesday), 2013** (Japan Standard Time,
>   JST)
> Launch time: **1:45:00 p.m. (JST)**
> Launch time windows: **1:45 p.m.
>   thru 2:30 p.m. (JST)**</s>

---

**Live Broadcast**

JAXA will broadcast the launch through the Internet. The live Internet broadcast will be provided in Flash format, YouTube and USTREAM from [this web page](http://www.jaxa.jp/countdown/epsilon/live_e.html).

**Broadcast Schedule**

<s>From 1:25 p.m. on August 27 (Tue.) (JST) *</s>

<sup>*The above schedule is subject to change due to the preparation status and weather conditions.</sup>

---

**Your local times for the start of the chat room event**

```
Timezone      Date        Local time
------------------------------------
Tokyo (JST)   August 27    1:25 p.m.
GMT/UTC       August 27    4:25 a.m.
CET/CEST      August 27    6:25 a.m.
EST/EDT       August 27   12:25 a.m.
PST/PDT       August 26    9:25 p.m.
```

[image: World Time]

If you can't find your timezone in the list above, you can use the [World Time Buddy](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/) tool.

---

**Welcome to our chat room - [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) - where we will discuss this event and post links to live streams covering the launch!**